# Why std::mutex can't be used with std::execution::par_unseq?

Tags: c++, std

According to the [execution_policy](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) `std::mutex` can't be used with `std::execution::par_unseq` with the following example on the page:

```
int x = 0;
std::mutex m;
int a[] = {1, 2};
std::for_each(std::execution::par_unseq, std::begin(a), std::end(a), [&](int)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(m); // Error: lock_guard constructor calls m.lock()
    ++x;
});
```

What is the specific reason or scenario which makes this illegal?

Is the main reason that with vectorization the code might try to get [std::mutex::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/lock) from the same thread and:

> If lock is called by a thread that already owns the mutex, the behavior is undefined: for example, the program may deadlock.

Or there is another explanation on what exactly and why could go wrong?

Comment: There's a detailed explanation on the page you cite. Starting with "Unsequenced execution policies are the only case where function calls are unsequenced with respect to each other, meaning they can be interleaved..."

Comment: The C++20 standard has a substantially similar example, with this text in the non-normative note: "The above program may result in two consecutive calls to `m.lock()` on the same thread of execution (which may deadlock), because the applications of the function object are not guaranteed to run on different threads of execution."

Comment: @IgorTandetnik, thank you. On the quote at the [en.cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t) that is exactly what caused my question, since nothing is explained behind this "interleaved"; no scenario why this could be an issue and your quote from standard helps to explain this and confirms my thoughts; thank you.